# Wordpress sidebar not align with content

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

Its driving me crazy as im not code whiz, using a template 'submate' im trying to add a right sidebar on a child theme vantage

```
<?php
/**
 * This template displays full width pages with a page title.
 *
 * @package vantage
 * @since vantage 1.0
 * @license GPL 2.0
 * 
 * Template Name: submate
 */
get_header(); ?>

<?php
//get the sidebar
$avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'page';
if(is_front_page()) { $avia_config['currently_viewing'] = 'frontpage'; }
get_sidebar();
?>
                <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <?php if(function_exists('bcn_display'))
    {
        bcn_display();
    }?>
</div>

    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

The link for it is;  http://www.seasonalharvest.co.uk/recipes/february/

Many thanks for any help :)

Comment: float the article left, and give it a width. You might want to get rid of the 3 level deep `<strong>` tags around the article too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html structure for article is very bad. You have wrapped your `article` element within `strong` element this doesn't make sense as it use for make the text bolder.

Anyway you can add this tiny snippet to your `wp-content/themes/your-theme/style.css`

```
article[class*="post"] { /* only post articles */
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
}
```

**Edit**

For specific page only:

```
.page-id-231 article[class*="post"] { /* only post articles */
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it sorted the problem however it has made all my other page articles that width

Comment: @user3359955 You only need for specific page? Please see my edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
<style type="text/css">
article#post-231 {
    float: left;
    width: 65%;
}
</style>
```